# How to save TF2 trained model and use it again for inference?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I used the following tutorial program (python3) to train a model to classify images as cat or dog.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

I could run this on my ubuntu computer but I want to save the trained model and try it again to test it with my own images.

Can you please point me to a code snippet to 
1. save the trained model and 
2. infer image.

Re @PSKP

I was able to save and load the model. Code is below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

dog = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
   "mowgli.JPG", grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=None,
    interpolation='nearest'
   )

 print(dog.size)

 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('dog-cat.h5')
 y_hat = model.predict(dog)

 print(y_hat)
```

But got this error at model.predict...

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

Thank you

Comment: As beginner, I am finding it hard to find end to end tutorial for image classification. Searching is hard as well. TF1, TF2, Python2, python3, Keras, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have number of ways of doing this. But I am showing you easiest way.

#### solution

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Train model

model.fit(...)

# Save Model
model.save("model_name.h5")

# Delete Model
del model

# Load Model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_name.h5')

# Now you can use model for inference
y_hat = model.predict(test_X)
```

## Edit

### Solution to `ValueError`

The problem is your `dog` variable is not numpy array or tensorflow tensor. Before using it you should convert it into numpy array. And also `model.predict(..)` does not accept only single image so you should add one extra dimension.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dog = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
   "mowgli.JPG", grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb', target_size=None,
    interpolation='nearest'
   )

# Convert to numpy array
dog = np.asarray(dog)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('dog-cat.h5')

# Add extrac Dimension (it depends on your model)
# This is because dog has only one image. But predict takes multiple
dog = np.array([dog])

y_hat = model.predict(dog)

print(y_hat)
```

## Find Other Solutions

[Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/)

Comment: I was able to read the image using  tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img but  model.predict gave me the error... ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>, <class 'NoneType'>.

Comment: I added new answer. If it worked for your problem Please Accept this answer.